# How to download MySQL db from Rails app in Cloud9 IDE

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, cloud9-ide

How can i download the MySQL db from a rails app in C9 (and then open locally in MySQL Workbench)?

I want to improve my skill in writing "raw SQL" queries and this would provide a lot of familiar data to play with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just export the db to a local file in c9, and then import it back on Your machine:

export:

```
mysqldump -u username -p databasename > backup.sql
```

import:

```
mysql -u username -p databasename < backup.sql
```

Comment: If you do this it asks for password. If leave password blank, there is an error `mysqldump: Got error: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '0.0.0.0' (111) when trying to connect`.

Comment: Just dont use '-p' tag. Works great. Check if username and DB name is correct: `mysqldump -u username databasename > backup.sql`

Comment: Unfortunately still getting a syntax error, `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near...'

Comment: ok, first of all You have to start the mysql if logged out of Your session. So, try this `mysql-ctl start` and then `mysqldump -u username databasename > backup.sql`

Comment: Was able to do it with `mysqldump <dbname> > backup.sql` !